# multi description meta tags in html head

Tags: zend-framework

in Zend FW when I add description meta tag in loop using helper:

`$this->headMeta()->appendName('DESCRIPTION', $des);`

i got multi meta tags in my html head.

```
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="des1" />
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="des2" />
```

how can i prevent it and have something like below in my html head:

```
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="des1 des2" />
```

Comment: Create $des using a loop and then add it to the tag

Comment: no it's not enough, because I want add to description anywhere i need, maybe in other view or plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend you own head view helper callable like this.

```
$this->headDescription($stringToAttach);
```

and offer a method to push the values to headMeta

```
$this->headDescription()->pushToHeadMeta();
// internal call like this
$this->view->headMeta('description', $this->getConcatedDescription());
```

Other option is to use placeholders.

```
//in view index.phtml
$this->placeholder('description')
     ->append($desc1);
//in view other.phtml
$this->placeholder('description')
     ->append($desc2);

// in layout
echo $this->headMeta('description', $this->placeholder('description'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Insted of

```
echo $this->headMeta ();
```

have in your layout

```
$u = '';
foreach ($this->headMeta ()->getContainer () as $y)
{
    if ($y->name == 'description')
    {
        $u .= $y->content;
    }
}
$this->headMeta ()->setName ('description', $u);

echo $this->headMeta ();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to get your metas as an array (I put it in /application/plugins/common.php you can put it where you want) :

```
public function getMetasArray(Zend_View $view){
        $metas = array();
        foreach ($view->headMeta()->getContainer() as $y)
        {
            if($y->name!=''){
                $metas[$y->name] = $y->content;
            }

        }
        return $metas;
    }
```

and to call it when you want and as you want :

```
$metas = Application_Plugin_Common::getMetasArray($this);
echo $metas['description'];
```